# Deterministic checksum of a git repository

Tags: git

I want to create a checksum of a (bare) git repository, so two equivalent repositories would have the same checksum. Is there git-idiomatic way to do that?

- tar + md5 won't work straightforward, because two repositories cloned at different time would have different timestamps, and tar stores timestamps
- even if timestamps are normalised, git pack files can be different for two repositories cloned from the same source (I don't know why they are different though, I guess either timestamps or file order).

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: It is for backups.

Comment: Can't you simply push to a backup remote using git itself?

Comment: You can try `git bundle`, see if that gives you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to know if two repos are *equivalent* rather than identical, and to do that you have to make up rules for what is or is not *equivalent*.

Internally git can represent "the same content" either as loose objects, or as packed objects.  A repo may have one pack, multiple packs, a combination of packs and loose objects.  I can't think of a reason two pack files would differ if their content were identical, but I wouldn't want to swear that they can't...

On the other hand, would you want to consider two repos equivalent if one uses LFS and the other doesn't (or if they use LFS to track different subsets of content)?  They might still contain exactly the same versions (as you'd see them by checking out to work trees), and a given version might be accessible in the same way (as long as that way is relative to a ref) from both... but being able to identify these as "equivalent" would make your job drastically more difficult (and more resource-intensive to run).  So I'll assume you don't have to worry about that, but the point is to underscore: no solution is truly general.

Well, enough philosophy:  Absent extreme conditions, you can do

```
git for-each-ref
```

to see every branch, tag, or other named entry point into the repo along with its current sha1.  If two refs (or two copies of a ref) have identical sha1 values, they have identical histories.  (A hash collision is not a realistic concern.)

You can feed that to `git hash-object`.  I'd sort it first (because I'm paranoid), and you might want to exclude remote refs (if the remote relationships don't matter), so

```
git for-each-ref |grep -v refs\/remotes |sort |git hash-object --stdin
```

(You could probably improve on the grep pattern I used, but for a quick-and-dirty one liner that should work pretty well.)

Comment: The sort step *would* be required if `git for-each-ref` did not already sort. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The SHA1 checksum of a given commit does almost exactly that. It uniquely (in the absence of SHA1 collisions) identifies the given commit, including all the history that led up to it. But that doesn't give you enough information for a repo with multiple independent branches.

Something like this pseudo-code is probably a good start:

```
For each branch (output of "git branch"):
    Run "git log -n 1" on that branch and capture the SHA1
Print all the collected SHA1s in sorted order and compute a checksum of the result.
```

This will not capture commits (including tagged commits) that are not on any branch. There's probably other information that this fails to capture -- though it's unlikely that two repos that yield the same result would have any real differences.

(Feel free to use this as the basis for a better answer.)